# Using SMS Authentication

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to test sending a SMS to the user when they need to sign the document. When do a GET of all envelope recipients i can see the SMS number there but the user never receives the SMS when it's time to sign. I'm using the dev sandbox to test this. Is this only available in production as a paid feature?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used Phone and KBA in DEMO, it doesn't charge.  You may have to check with DocuSign to enable it.  You should be able to check by going into the *Console --> Send tab --> add a recipient*.  Pull down the *identity* tab and see if you have it listed.

[image: authorization options]

You have `requireIdLookup=false` in your example.  That should be true, and you also need to set IDCheckConfigurationName to the right value.

```
recipient.RequireIDLookup = true;
recipient.IDCheckConfigurationName = "SMS Auth $";
```